# A question about the Alpha Values of images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
  // Make half-transparent grey, the background color for the layer
   UIColor *Light_Grey 
      = [UIColor colorWithRed : 110/255.0 
                        green : 110/255.0 
                        blue  : 110/255.0 
                        alpha : 0.5];

  // Get a CGColor object with the same color values
   CGColorRef cgLight_Grey = [Light_Grey CGColor];
   [boxLayer setBackgroundColor : cgLight_Grey];

  // Create a UIImage
   UIImage *layerImage = [UIImage imageNamed : @"Test.png"];

  // Get the underlying CGImage
   CGImageRef image = [layerImage CGImage];

  // Put the CGImage on the layer
   [boxLayer setContents : (id) image];
```

Consider the above sample code segment.

**UIColor *Light_Grey** is set with an alpha value of 0.5.  My question is : Is there anyway I can set the alpha value of **CGImageRef image**?

The reason of my asking this is even though the alpha value of **boxLayer** is 0.5, any images set on top of **BoxLayer** seem to have an alpha default value of 1, which would cover up anything lying directly underneath the images.

Hope that somebody knowledgable on this can help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you can make a copy using [`CGImageCreate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) and use the decode array to rescale the alpha (e.g. 0.0-0.5)

> decode
>
> The decode array for the image. If you
>   do not want to allow remapping of the
>   image’s color values, pass NULL for
>   the decode array. For each color
>   component in the image’s color space
>   (including the alpha component), a
>   decode array provides a pair of values
>   denoting the upper and lower limits of
>   a range. For example, the decode array
>   for a source image in the RGB color
>   space would contain six entries total,
>   consisting of one pair each for red,
>   green, and blue. When the image is
>   rendered, Quartz uses a linear
>   transform to map the original
>   component value into a relative number
>   within your designated range that is
>   appropriate for the destination color
>   space.

Comment: Thanks for your kind assistance and detailed answer.  I was actually hoping for some easier way to adjust the Alpha value.  Seems that there may not be a direct way of doing this.  Will look into CGImageCreate to see if I can manage to get it to work.

Comment: No problem.  If I read the docs correctly, a decode array of "0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5" should give you the desired effect (although I've not tried it myself.)